# Does UILabel have a limited maximum height

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel

I want to show some text that is very long. but when my UIlabel height over 8184,it become invisible.
The thing is: I create a UIScrollView and add a UILabel as subview. when I got a text that is 24,000 long, then the label become invisible. After some test, I found that when the height of UILabel is over 8184, it disappears. Does someone meet this problem. Does UILabel have a maximum height?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but since there's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623317/does-uilabel-have-a-maximum-height) with the same problem, UILabel does indeed have a maximum possible height. But, also UILabel isn't made to show a large amount of text - it's a label. Why aren't you using [UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/)?

Comment: @p4sh4, I want to use UITextView, but how to place some other UI kits.I looked into another question, but the answer doesn't do to me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `UILabel` for long characters you can use `UITextView`. And after setting your content, do `enable=NO;`. Then no one can edit your content and it will behave like `UILabel`.

Comment: There are some other UIKits in the scrollview, like image view and button.If I changed to UITextView, how to place other UI Kits.